# iOS: audio MP3 file path

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin.forms, mp3, filepath

I am using Xamarin Forms to create my mobile application.  I downloaded the XamarinAudioManager package to play the MP3 files and am using this line of code to set the path.

```
            Audio.Manager.SoundPath = "/Users/TaylorWong/Projects/test/test/Sounds";
```

The files play on the iPhone simulator on my computer, but not on my actual iPhone. I am having trouble with the audio file path.  I don't think the files are being accessed even though I have them saved in the iOS Resources folder, within a Sounds folder, in Visual Studios as well as my computer. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how XamarinAudioManager works but I think You have to add the files to Resources folder and just set the name of the mp3 file, be sure that your files have the build action = bundle resources.

```
Audio.Manager.SoundPath = "YourFileName.mp3"
```

if you have sub-folder use like this

```
Audio.Manager.SoundPath = "subfolder/YourFileName.mp3"
```

Comment: I simply took out the line of code where I stated the path because the default Xamarin Manager sound path was already set to "Sounds" inside the Resources folder.  I had named the folder with the MP3 files "Sounds" in my app as well and it now works! Thanks!